# MDT 2013 "Windows Components missing"

Tags: windows, windows-7, drivers, mdt, mdt-2013

i have an environment running MDT 2013 and i have multiple different models for (dell/lenovo) desktops and laptops.

i captured an image and it runs well on all the computers except a specific lenovo models which are (L440, L450, T440, T450) i downloaded the SCCM package and injected the drivers into the Out of box drivers and created a selection profile to assign the correct drivers for these models. error occurs "windows could not configure one or more system components" i searched deeper and the only option i found is to open the regedit and then go to (HKLM_System_setup_status_childcompletition_setup) and change the value to (3) instead of (1)
it worked also when i uploaded only the Ethernet and chipset drivers only on the MDT, but it is a big hassle to install each driver manually.

please help

Comment: What OS are you trying to deploy?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise and Professional

Comment: Have you tried deploying the image without customizations? E.g. from a DVD but using MDT to add the items post install? Also are you using the latest MDT update? It should be update 2

Comment: yes and it works normally however the problem seems in the drivers

Comment: Mount the WIM image you're trying to deploy and then mount the registry (the system hive, located at `\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`) and edit the key manually. Unload the hive and then commit the image upon unmounting it. Deploy and profit!
(If this works then I will write it as an answer with screenshots)

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: hello i tried it but still the same issue, 
i tried another workaround and created a new task sequence for these models and it worked so it's obvious that it is a drivers problem from lenovo, i also don't understand why this key has changed ..

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Can you post the answer for your issue? Thanks!

Comment: yes sure 
1. imported the lenovo drivers with it's "Machine Type model" into the out of box drivers
2.created a new "Selection profile" with the name of the laptop model (example Thinkpad T440) and directed it to the out of box drivers
3.created a new task sequence then modified "Inject drivers" option and made it to "install all the drivers from the recent selection profile created"
that solved the problem for me